# Ionic app, Error: ..main.ts Module build failed: Error: ENOENT

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

Here I have Ionic v4 app with Firebase and Google integration

Ionic info shows this:

```
Ionic:
   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 22 other plugins)

System:
   NodeJS : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Main.ts contains just this

```
 {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The problem arises after I run: `ionic build android`

```
[15:54:08]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[15:54:08]  Error: C:/PATH/Ionic/src/app/main.ts Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no
            such file or directory, open 'C:\PATH\Ionic\src\app\main.js'
Error: C:/Users/Jasko/Dropbox/Projects/Real.Me/Ionic/src/app/main.ts
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\PATH\Ionic\src\app\main.js'
    at new BuildError (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at callback (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack.js:121:28)
    at emitRecords.err (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:265:13)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:371:38)
    at emitAssets.err (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:258:10)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:364:12)
    at next (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\webpack\lib\performance\SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:222:13)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (C:\PATH\Ionic\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:361:9)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
```

Anyone with idea where to look for error ?

Comment: I am not sure but you might need to run ``ionic cordova build android`` instead

Answer (score -1):

**The problem was caused with windows Symlink folder. as soon i moved source code to another drive it ran successfully. Definitely a Ionic BUG**